# Better resolution for pdf file in Texstudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio, resolution

I notice that the quality of the viewer of Texstudio is much better than that of the pdf file it creates. It seems that some quality is lost during the conversion. See below for the comparison. Is there a way to retain the same quality of the viewer in the pdf file? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Viewer:
[image]

Pdf:

[image]

Comment: I suppose this has just to do with your pdf viewer and its settings... You can try some different viewers and see there the results. There are many free out there

Comment: Thanks, @koleygr. How simple it is! I never thought of it. You were right. I used an out dated Adobe version. Just tested it with the newer Adobe reader and got the quality I like. Thank a bunch :)

Comment: Are there fonts of Type 3 (bitmap fonts) in the document? Check with `pdffonts` or Adobe Reader/document properties/fonts. These kind of fonts are usually the cause of this kind of quality problem. Some PDF viewers can compensate by anti-aliasing, but this does not solve the cause of the problem. (BTW, TeXstudio just views the PDF file with its integrated PDF viewer.)

Comment: @koleygr, pls recommend one good third party reader? Thanks.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I am happy with the quality the newer version of Adobe reader DC gives me.

Comment: @hochoi I use only open source viewers under linux.... take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software and test some of them

Comment: Check with a large magnification, are the glyphs still smooth or can you see pixel blocks?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, under magnification, everything is smooth. No pixel.

Comment: Then, the PDF seems fine (especially, if there are no font of Type 3).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, yes, the pdf is fine. It was the outdated reader.